# props value reset to 0 and NaN in reactjs component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

So I am trying to make a simple Typing App in reactjs, But I am facing an issue while passing values of Accuracy and WPM to another Component ResultsPage.js. The values are correct in App.js and are passed correctly to ResultsPage.js too(by seeing console.log) but then resets to 0.
Here is my return code block of **App.js**

```
 return (
    <div>
      <h1>Type the paragraph:</h1>
      <h2>{currentParagraph}</h2>
      <textarea
        ref={inputRef}
        value={typedText}
        onChange={handleChange}
        disabled={!isPlaying}
        rows={6}
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
      />
      {showResults ? (
        <ResultsPage
          accuracy={accuracy}
          wpm={wpm}
          onTryAgain={() => setShowResults(false)}
        />
      ) : (
        <div>
          {isPlaying ? (
            <div>
              Time remaining: {timeRemaining}
              <br />
              Accuracy: {accuracy.toFixed(2)}%<p>WPM: {wpm.toFixed(0)}</p>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="timer-length">Timer length:</label>
              <input
                id="timer-length"
                type="number"
                value={timerLength}
                onChange={(event) => setTimerLength(Number(event.target.value))}
              />
              <button onClick={handleStartClick}>Start</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

This is where Im calculating **WPM and Accuracy**

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Calculate the accuracy as the number of correctly typed words divided by the total number of words
    const currentWords = currentParagraph.split(" ");
    const totalWords = currentWords.length;
    const typedWords = typedText.split(" ");
    const correctWords = typedWords.reduce((total, word, index) => {
      if (word === currentWords[index]) {
        return total + 1;
      }
      return total;
    }, 0);
    setAccuracy((correctWords / typedWords.length) * 100);
    // console.log("acc" + accuracy);
    // Calculate the WPM as the number of correctly typed words divided by the time elapsed, multiplied by 60 seconds
    const elapsedTime = timerLength - timeRemaining;
    let totalChars = 0;
    typedWords.forEach((word, index) => {
      if (word === currentWords[index]) {
        totalChars += word.length + 1; // +1 to count the space
      }
    });
    setWpm((totalChars / 5 / elapsedTime) * 60);
    //console.log("wpm" + wpm);
  }, [currentParagraph, typedText, timerLength, timeRemaining]);
```

This is ResultsPage.js

```
function ResultsPage(props) {
  // Set default values for accuracy and wpm
  const { accuracy = 0, wpm = 0, onTryAgain } = props;

   console.log("," + accuracy + "," + wpm);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Your accuracy was {accuracy}%</p>
      <p>Your WPM was {wpm}</p>
      <button onClick={onTryAgain}>Try Again</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ResultsPage;
```

This is the output:
[image]

This is after the timer runs out and ResultsPage component is called:
[image]

Comment: Where do you set wpm?

Comment: @JacobEngineer Updated my Question to Include the useEffect hook where Im setting WPM and Accuracy

Comment: Is the default value of wpm and accuracy null?

Comment: @RahulPurohit 
``` 
const [accuracy, setAccuracy] = useState(0);
const [wpm, setWpm] = useState(0);
```